# How to send a zip file to gmail which contains javascript, Extension as zip is not present

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am facing an issue with sending a file which is actually a zip file containing some reports using js files.

Previously, As we know Gmail has blocked some extensions so I removed extension as .zip and the file was sending fine by Gmail.

Getting error for below reason:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

But now even my file which does not have extension as .zip is not sending by Gmail

Below URL having the Extensions which are blocked by Gmail:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30030/how-to-allow-gmail-to-receive-zip-files

Any workaround will be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Rename the file extension of the zip file from '.zip' to '.crx'. You will be able to include any files in the archive.

For example:
files.zip -> files.crx

Answer (score 2):

just upload the file to something like drop box and then share the link to it?

Comment: Hi @Mark - thanks for replying ... Can I upload cucumber report in gist?

Comment: Cucumber reports are containing some js files

Comment: Reason is I want to sent report of execution and snapshot to client and related member in daily bases when Jenkins start execution of test cases by scheduler

Comment: Well perhaps use a file sharing system like drop box, use their API to upload your files and then send a link to the new file in your email, much better than duplicating all that data in emails. There's lots of examples of how to achieve this in various languages.

Comment: I have implemented dropbox uploading after your suggestion. voting you up for now. Still keep this thread open if any options appears for Gmail